# Flutter dynamic height gridview

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a notes app that has a gridview with max 2 columns, and each note (container) will have a dynamic height. Meaning, if the content in the note is very short <50 characters, it should have a shorter height compared to another note which has more characters. Example screenshot below:

[Sample screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/nQAD6yo)

Comment: You can use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

Add below package :

```
 flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
```

Below are the list of strings that needs to display

```
List<String> items = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori",
    "i ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep",
    " dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tem",
    "liquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in ",
    "lpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "eniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, q",
    "t in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "sfgdf",
    "i ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep",
    " dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tem",
    "liquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in ",
    "lpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "eniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, q",
    "t in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "sfgdf",
  ];
```

Below is the sample of build view

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: StaggeredGrid.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 12,
              children: items
                  .map((item) => Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                        child: Text(item),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

It will look like this,

[image]